# Should you bin data when creating moving average to generate a forecast?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, unevenly-spaced-time-series

Let's say I have insurance claims that are created on a daily basis on Monday through Friday but sometimes there will be days in which we don't get a claim, perhaps it'll be a week or two that we don't get a claim.

If I want to calculate a 3-month moving average, is it best to first calculate total claims received by month and then calculate the **3-month moving average**?  Or would it be best to calculate total claims by date such as claims received on 5/10/2021, 5/11/2021, etc., and then calculate the **90-day moving average**?

My gut tells me that grouping by month to calculate the monthly totals may hide the underlying trend that could only be captured by looking at daily totals. Thanks!

Comment: What do you need to calculate it for? How are you planning to use the result?

Comment: The main goal is to generate a forecast of future claims. Thank you.